# How to decrease stickiness of Box Collider when using Platform Effector 2D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, physics

I am implementing a platform that players can jump onto from underneath, going through the platform in the up direction and landing on it in the down. I am able to get the access correct (user can correctly pass through), however, when a user doesn't jump all the way through, they are currently able to hang onto the platform.

I created and applied a Physics Material 2D and put both bounce and friction to zero, however, I can't seem to figure out why the player gets stuck on it.

Adding a video: https://imgur.com/dfNH4su.mp4

(Annoyingly, this is unintended but... gave ideas for future features!... hang time ) Thank you in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: There's actually no code for this bit, this is using the Platform Effector 2D component.

Comment: I think it's working! The solution I used was to enable One Way Grouping which is defined as:

Ensures that all contacts disabled by the one-way behaviour act on all colliders. This is useful when multiple colliders are used on the object passing through the platform and they all need to act together as a group.

Comment: oké nice, never heard of that component, seems great! Glad you found your own solution!